# In QGIS import/update multiple layers from single spreadsheet

Tags: qgis, import, select-by-attribute, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet I regularly update with new data. It contains X, Y and several column pairs. How does one assign in one operation information from the pairs (and associated X,Y) to their respective delimited text layers for plotting?
I convert Excel file to csv then add "delimited Text Layer". Example from  spreadsheet, pairs cols e&f, g&h etc:[image] Also Edit greyed-out in attribute table.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your input data? Which software you want to use?

Comment: From Excel I make a csv then "add delimited text layer" to my project. Not all cells are populated.

Comment: From Excel I make a csv then "add delimited text layer" to my project. Not all cell pairs populated. Few lines & header shown, pairs 'S0 Dip' 'S0 Dipdir' etc:Year Stn East North S0 Dip S0 Dipdir S0 OT Dip S0 OT Dipdir S1 Dip S1 Dipdir L1 Plunge L1 Pldir Unit notes   
R0 R00-003 601110 5502050   60 294          KKQ 
R0 R00-004a 601090 5502050   55 306 48 303 14 226  OT,  L1 calc, KKQ and arg interbeds 
R0 R00-004b 601080 5502060   80 297 56 288 17 210  OT, L1 calc. 
R0 R00-004c 601100 5502070   59 307 55 315       
R0 R00-005a 601100 5502100   65 287 42 318 22 4  OT, lam Arg in 1 m KKQ

Comment: Please update your question with the new information